# Не прерывать выполнение команды даже после разрыва связи с сервером

Tags: linux, scp, gnu-screen, tmux

Переношу 27тб с одного сервера на другой по ssh:

```
 scp -r /home/ root@192.168.0.2:/home2/
```

Консоль открываю в мозиле (FireSSH), при закрытии вкладки с консолью копирование обрывается, как продолжить копирование с закрытым терминалом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Откройте xterm (или другой терминал) дайте команду в фоновом режиме

```
scp -r /home/ root@192.168.0.2:/home2/ &
```

Comment: а ещё лучше запустить в screen/tmux и использовать rsync.

Comment: @Yaroslav  я запускаю терминал на окнах, в Putty  есть возможность фонового режима?

Comment: @РоманМальцев, это не имеет никакого отношения к возможностям putty.

Comment: Получилось перевести команду в фоновый режим. Но вопрос, если создаю новую сессию (другое окно консоли). И мне нужно просмотреть фоновые задачи с прошлой сессии, как это сделать, jobs пустой

Comment: Я пользуюсь htop

Answer (score 8):

в подобных случаях удобно пользоваться [мультиплексором терминала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80).

при создании новой сессии мультиплексора внутри будет (автоматически) запущен сеанс оболочки, где и можно будет запустить «долгоиграющую» программу. даже пропадание связи (между вашим локальным компьютером и компьютером, где вы запустили сессию мультиплексора) не прекратит работу сессии мультиплексора, и, соответственно, сеанса оболочки и запущенной в нём программы.

и, что бывает немаловажно, после переподключения вы увидите всё (в пределах размера буфера мультиплексора, конечно), что вывела «долгоиграющая» программа.

---

минимальные примеры использования для наиболее распространённых мультиплексоров [gnu/screen](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) и [tmux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux):

### gnu/screen

- просмотреть список сессий, запущенных на данном компьютере:

  ```
    $ screen ls
  ```
- создать именованную сессию (или подключиться к существующей):

  ```
    $ screen -RD имя_сессии
  ```
- отключиться от сессии:

  <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

### tmux

- просмотреть список сессий, запущенных на данном компьютере:

  ```
    $ tmux ls
  ```
- создать именованную сессию:

  ```
    $ tmux new -s имя_сессии
  ```
- подключиться к существующей сессии:

  ```
    $ tmux a -t имя_сессии
  ```
- отключиться от сессии:

  <kbd>ctrl+b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

---

завершится сессия при завершении сеанса оболочки, который работает внутри сессии. это, как обычно, можно сделать либо командой:

```
$ exit
```

либо нажатием <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd>