# Выполнение команды на сервере после отключения

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер

У меня стоит на сервере Ubuntu 16. Как запустить команду, например, на заливку дампа базы (он у меня заливается несколько часов), отключится и что бы заливка продолжалась. Потому что сейчас, если я отключаюсь, оно перестает заливаться

Comment: в консоли напишите `man nohup`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536557/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, документация (отдельной сущностью) ваще как нужна. И да, я видел тред на мете.

Comment: @donRumata вы имеете в виду такой же раздел Documentation, как на enSO?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ага. Тогда можно будет говорить "RTFM!!! <ссылка на доку>".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В конце строки команды поставьте символ '&'. После запуска процесс уйдёт в фон и отцепится от терминала. После этого терминал можно закрыть.