# Перенаправление вывода в файл в фоновом режиме

Tags: linux, asterisk

Команда пишет в файл `command > file.txt`, но при этом терминал становится не доступным.

Если использовать `command > file.txt &`, то выдается такое сообщение `Остановлено (вывод на терминал)` и в файл ничего не пишется.

Вопрос: Как запустить команду так, чтобы она выполнялась в фоновом режиме с записью в файл.

Comment: Странно, у меня `command > file.txt &` отлично работает

Comment: @andreymal а возможно, что данная команда запускает CLI ? и по этому не работает запись в файл

Comment: Попробуйте `command &> file.txt&`  А вообще было-бы проще, если бы Вы хотя-бы намекнули, что это за команда.

Comment: @Fisherman `asterisk -rv`

Comment: ... но зачем? `asterisk -r` — по определению интерактивный процесс. Зачем его загонять в background?  Ну на край screen, но всё-таки — зачем?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev отваливается одна учетка время от времени, закономерности нету, вот хочу на пару дней запустить, чтобы собиралась хоть какая-то статистика

Comment: А можно медленно и по порядку? А то я не понял / не увидел связи.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev я не знаю как правильно отловить отключения учетной записи на астериске, первое что пришло в голову, это записать вывод консоли в файл. Но если просто указать `command > file.txt`, то нужно оставлять окно терминала активным. Поэтому я и подумал засунуть выполнение данной команды в background

Comment: Что такое "учётная запись" и её отключение в вашем контексте — вот что я пытаюсь уточнить.

Comment: воспользуйтесь любым доступным [терминальным мультиплексором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536557/178576)

Comment: а ещё хорошим способом будет увеличить log level самого астерикса, а потом посмотреть логи...

Comment: Всем спасибо, сделал.

Comment: Generic solution `man nohup`.