# Сеанс SSH PuTTY в Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, putty

Захожу на VDS Ubuntu 16.04 по SSH с помощью PuTTY. Запускаю скрипт php, который работает продолжительное время и выводит в консоль сообщения по мере работы.
Если я закрываю PuTTY (либо произошел обрыв связи с сервером). То при повторном подключении под тем же пользователем вижу ожидание очередной команды Ubuntu, хотя скрипт php продолжает работу.

Вопросы:

1) Как вернуться к запущенному php-скрипту, чтобы видеть какие результаты он пишет в консоль? Да и не только php-скрипт, а например тот же htop.

2) Под одним и тем же пользователем я могу несколько раз подключиться. Это нормально, что эти подключения "не видят" друг друга? И предыдущее подключение не закрывается. Почему так происходит?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536557/178576

Comment: *Это нормально, что эти подключения "не видят" друг друга?* да. вы ведь каждый раз запускаете новый экземпляр оболочки.