# Как остановить бота python на сервере?

Tags: python

Установил бота на сервер, всё работает, но как мне его остановить теперь? Помогите плсс
Устанавливал через termius с помощью screen

Comment: Ну очень абстрактный вопрос, показали бы хоть как устанавливали)

Comment: всё что угодно предоставлю, только скажите что?) Правил вопрос, но этого вряд ли достаточно

Comment: [надо подключиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536557/178576) и нажать ctrl+c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В консоль напиши `top` и найди PID Python скрипта и также напиши в консоль `sudo kill PID` вместо PID те цифры которые ты нашла в `top`

Comment: очень много чего то развернулось, после команды топ, в основном всё рут, как найти пид пайтон скрипта среди этого?

Comment: @АлинаБолт `ps aux | grep python` ;)

Comment: Чужь полная... Не в коем случае не надо так поступать

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer аргументируйте

Comment: @Интик 1. У человека может стоять несколько скриптов 2. Screen так и не будет закрыт, и в итоге может быть 100-200 открытых screen,а они жрут довольно прилично

Answer (score 2):

Если вы включали скрипт через `screen`, то можно поступить так:

1. Пропишите `screen -ls` данная команда выдаст вам все запущенные сессии
2. Пропишите команду `screen -XS название сессии quit` - с помощью данной команды вы закроете нужную вам сессию