# Как запустить скрин python на виртуальной машине ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, виртуальная-машина

На виртуальной машине в докере запущены контейнеры python и postgres, также загружен и запущен скрипт python. Виртуальная машина работает круглосуточно, но при закрытии терминала ubuntu на локальной машине скрипт завершает работу. Как при завершении работы его автоматически запускать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не прерывать выполнение команды даже после разрыва связи с сервером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523253/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, тут наверное даже больше https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416

Comment: @donRumata, только метки там странные. называются: «фиг найдёшь».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, эммм... не распарсил. Что за метки?

Comment: @donRumata bash и bat. метки у вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а, действительно. Я посмотрел историю изменений - там изначально был указан `CentOS 7`. Так что всё **было** логично.