# Терминал в Ubuntu занят процессом, как открыть ещё несколько процессов?

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, консоль

Терминал в Ubuntu занят процессом, как открыть ещё несколько процессов?
У меня к примеру запущен сервер через терминал, а мне нужно запустить ещё несколько процессов как это сделать? Ubuntu серверная без оболочки

Comment: Ну так там ещё пяток терминалов на ctrl-alt-2..6

Comment: @AlexeyTen зажать ctrl + alt и осткоется ещё терминал?

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` - процесс сервера остановится, `bash$ bg` - процесс сервера возобновится в фоне, затем `bash$ cmd1 &`, `bash$ cmd2 &`, `bash$ cmd3 &` - Запустить команды 1,2,3 в фоне

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523253/178576