# Как запустить приложения .netcore на ububtu так что бы она не закрывалась после закрытия терминала

Tags: ubuntu

Я делаю так ./Prog
Но после закрытия терминала приложения тоже закрывается.
Попробовал так "./Prog &" но это попадает в список jobs ([1]+ Stopped ./Prog)
и нужно запустить так "fg". Команда "fg" тоже закрывается когда закрываем терминал.

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не прерывать выполнение команды даже после разрыва связи с сервером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523253/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

Создаем файл сервиса

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-<your_app>.service
```

Откроется редактор nano. Вставляем туда текст, редактируем его, заменяя названия папок и файлов на свои

```
[Unit]
Description=<App Name>

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/<app_folder>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/<app_folder>/<app_name>.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Далее выполняем 2 команды для активации и запуска сервиса, который мы только что создали

```
sudo systemctl enable kestrel-<app_name>.service
sudo systemctl start kestrel-<app_name>.service
```

Конец. Сервис запущен в фоновом режиме. Если хотите видеть, что выводит ваша .NET программа, то выполните

```
sudo systemctl status kestrel-<app_name>.service
```

Если хотите остановить сервис, перезапустить или деактивировать, то вот список команд которые точно пригодятся

```
sudo systemctl <enable/disable/start/stop/restart> kestrel-<app_name>.service
```

kestrel в названии .service файла тоже не обязательно использовать. Подойдет любое название файла. Просто чаще всего .NET программы запускаются на kestrel сервере. Так потом проще понять по одному только названию файла что он делает и за что отвечает