# Как запустить несколько ботов на сервере?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ubuntu

Всем привет, арендовал сервер на ubuntu, одного бота спокойно запускаю, но как запустить других? Платформа - node.js

Comment: запускайте на разных портах просто и все.

Comment: Точно так же, как и одного бота, но несколько раз

Comment: [примерно дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523253/178576)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще. Помог мне в этом screen.
Ничего сложного, документация легко гуглится ([вот ссылочка](https://itman.in/ssh-screen))

Answer (score 4):

В этом вопросе я вижу два возможных *настоящих вопроса*:

1. Как запуститьнесколько экземпляров node.js с неким кодом на одном сервере и при этом удобно управлять ими?

Спрашиваете - отвечаем! Мне по душе пришлась аппликуха [**pm2**](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/). Это такой  process-менеджер, который позволяет запусткать, проверять, останавливать и "контролировать, что работет" процессы, запущенные под node.js Есть [вот такая статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/480670/) про это process-manager.

2. Как сделатьтак, что несколько ботов запущены на одноми том же сервере, *на одном и том же порту* и, тем не менее, к ним можно обращаться?

Здесь краткий ответ такой: по своей сути, бот является специализированным WEB - сервером.

Начиная с версии протокола HTTP 1.1 можно хостить несколько сайтов на одном хосте и на одном порту. При этом веб-сервер берет из HTTP-заголовков имя того сайта, от которого пришел запрос, и передаёт этот запрос соответствующему обработчику.

Разберем на примере.

Пусть мы хоим на одном хосте запустить двух ботов (А и Б). Тогда мы делаем так:

1. запускаем ботов на разных портах локалхоста, пусть это порты 80 и 81.
2. Дадим им DNS-имена *bota.mysite.ru* и *botb.mysite.ru*
3. запускаем nginx и пишем для него конфиг, который заставляет nginx быть http-прокси, для двух DNS-имен, которые мы дали ботам.

Результат - снаружи боты видны по их DNS-именам по стандартным портам. Еще можно на nginx "повесить" задачу хостинга ssl-сертификатов.

Если по каким то пунктам ответа нужно сделать уточнения - напишите обэтом в комментариях!

Comment: Не сильно вчитывался в pm2, но чем не устроил обычный `systemd unit`?

Comment: @donRumata - Вы правы, просто pm2 - это такой упрощённый мультиплатформенный инструмент, для тех кто в линуксе "не очень"...

Comment: А можно в ответ дополнительно бахнуть пример синтаксиса реальной задачи? Мне бы оценить на сколько это "сложнее".

Comment: я постараюсь залезть на сервер, на котором последний раз это настраивал, но, мне кажется, там все как то очень элементарно.... pm2 start <имя *.js> в директории, где лежит js-файл. pm2 list - показывает список запущенных задач, сколько памяти они скушали т.п. Вы правы - я добавлю это в ответ, потому что это сделает ответ полнее :-)